# Django Rest Framework how to customize ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have two models, `Survey` and `Question`. A `Survey` can contain multiple `Question`. I want to create a `ListAPIView` to return a list of `Surveys` with `Questions` associated with them. So the returned json would look like this:

```
[{
     'name': 'Survey 1',
     'questions':[{'question': 'q1'}, {'question': 'q2'}]
 },
 {
     'name': 'Survey 2',
     'questions':[{'question': 'q3'}, {'question': 'q4'}]
 },
 ...
]
```

I want to use the `CursorPagination` that comes with the DRF package. So here is what I have tried:

```
class SurveyList(ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = CursorPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        # How can I construct a queryset that matches the JSON structure above?
```

Since ListAPIView's `get_queryset` expects a queryset to be returned. I need to manually create a JSON structure described above and put it into a queryset.

So my question is how to manually create a queryset?

---

Update: here is the model definition

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create custom serializer for your model:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question',)

class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(source="question_set", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('name', 'questions')
        depth = 1
```

In your view:

```
class SurveyList(ListAPIView):
     queryset = Survey.objects.all()
     serializer_class = SurveySerializer
```

In case if you have `ForeignKey` to `Question` in your `Survey` model. If you don't replace `question_set` with name of your field.

Checkout [serializers section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) in django rest framework documentation.

Comment: Hi Daniil, this definitely looks promising. I have updated the model definition. I wonder if the `source=question_set` and `depth=1` part are needed.

Comment: `depth=1` means that serializer will travel deeper to find your relation (I don't really remember if it has default value). `question_set ` is required because relation with `Questions` is technically outside of your model (by default Django REST framework will try to serialize only that fields that your  defined in your model)

Comment: Hi Daniil, I read the docs but cannot find the explanation about `question_set`. For the format `?_set`, the ? part has to match the name of the model?

Comment: @Cheng, this is standart related object reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/

Comment: thanks again! Do you think something like this would work too: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: @Cheng yes, pay attention to `related_name` argument :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97253/discussion-between-cheng-and-daniil-ryzhkov).